# Javascript/jQuery to get subarray value with random array key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have these below JSON data:

```
{
"0": {
    "jQuery331045811028719032642": {
        "stepCount": 1,
        "captionSize": 0,
        "countdown": true,
        "countdownAlertLimit": 10,
        "displayCaptions": false,
        "displayDays": 0,
        "displayHours": true,
        "fontFamily": "Verdana, sans-serif",
        "fontSize": 0,
        "lang": "en",
        "languages": {},
        "seconds": 2609,
        "start": true,
        "theme": "white",
        "width": 4,
        "height": 30,
        "gap": 11,
        "vals": [0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 9],
        "limits": [2, 9, 5, 9, 5, 9],
        "iSec": 5,
        "iHour": 1,
        "tickTimeout": 1000,
        "intervalId": 1,
        "tickCount": 0,
        "timeTo": "2021-06-12T15:14:00.000Z",
        "options": {
            "timeTo": "2021-06-12T15:14:00.000Z",
            "start": true,
            "theme": "white",
            "seconds": 2609
        },
        "sec": 2609,
        "ttStartTime": 1623508230144
    },
    "jQuery331045811028719032641": {
        "hasDataAttrs": true
    }
},
"length": 1
}
```

Assume above array variable is `var data`;

For this subarray `jQuery331045811028719032642` is auto generate.

My question, how to get `seconds` array value using jQuery?

I tried this:

```
alert(data[0].seconds);
```

but it returns undefined.

Comment: There is no `seconds` array in the complete object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `seconds` using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
const data = {
  "0": {
    jQuery331045811028719032642: {
      stepCount: 1,
      captionSize: 0,
      countdown: true,
      countdownAlertLimit: 10,
      displayCaptions: false,
      displayDays: 0,
      displayHours: true,
      fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif",
      fontSize: 0,
      lang: "en",
      languages: {},
      seconds: 2609,
      start: true,
      theme: "white",
      width: 4,
      height: 30,
      gap: 11,
      vals: [0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 9],
      limits: [2, 9, 5, 9, 5, 9],
      iSec: 5,
      iHour: 1,
      tickTimeout: 1000,
      intervalId: 1,
      tickCount: 0,
      timeTo: "2021-06-12T15:14:00.000Z",
      options: {
        timeTo: "2021-06-12T15:14:00.000Z",
        start: true,
        theme: "white",
        seconds: 2609,
      },
      sec: 2609,
      ttStartTime: 1623508230144,
    },
    jQuery331045811028719032641: {
      hasDataAttrs: true,
    },
  },
  length: 1,
};
const zeroObj = data["0"];
const result = Object.values(zeroObj)[0].seconds;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this code

```
const arrayData = Object.values(data["0"]);
console.log(arrayData[0].seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of them to get the seconds value.

1- Use Object.values to get the values inside the Object like below

```
let res = Object.values(data["0"]);
let seconds = res.seconds; // This will give you value of seconds.
```

2- Use Object.keys to get the keys of object and get the data using that key.

```
let keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
let seconds = data[0][keys[0]].seconds;
```